# How do I install iTunes?

Tags: wine, itunes, winetricks

I have an iPhone and run Ubuntu on all of my personal computers. Since I did not want to keep a separate partition with Windows on it for the sole purpose of running iTunes, I attempted to install It using Wine.

I installed Wine 1.4 from the Software Center and installed iTunes 10.6.3. When I tried to run it I got a slew of error messages. I hopped over to google where it was suggested that I install it through PlayOnLinux. I did so with the same result. Further googling revealed that iTunes 10.6.x is confirmed to work with Wine 1.5.1 and up.

I installed Wine 1.5.1 following the instructions I found and was unable to get it to open. I did the same with 1.5.9 with the same results. I opened the Package Manager and installed the Wine 1.5.9 packages through it, and it appears to have installed properly.

When trying to install iTunes I got he error "This iTunes installer requires Windows Vista 64 bit or later". Realizing that Wine uses XP as a default I ran winecfg and changed it to Windows 7. This changed nothing and I tried changing it through winetricks to no avail. I even changed it to Vista with the same results.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Just mentioning this rhythmbox can open iphone and import/export music to it and shotwell can easily import/export foto's from it

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately Apple does not support the Linux platform when it comes to their products. Even if you manage to install iTunes with `wine`, it won't work like it would say on a Mac or Windows set up.

Rythmbox and many Linux media players (from personal experience) will be able to snyc and play your songs without a problem.

The best option for you is to install [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and install Windows your guest OS, iTunes should install and work your iPhone.

Here is a guide on  [how to install Windows XP on Ubuntu with Virtualbox](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-XP-on-Ubuntu-with-VirtualBox).

However (from personal experience) do not try updating the firmware of your phone with virtualbox as it does not work like on a native OS.

Comment: May I ask something? Wouldn't he still need processor extensions like VT-D to allow device passthrough? Or is it handled by the USB passthrough built into VBOX?

Comment: Well it works for me with only guest additions and extension pack installed

Answer (score 3):

To prevent iTunes from detecting a 64bit environment, see this guide:
[How to force Wine into acting like 32-bit Windows on 64-bit Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136714/how-to-force-wine-into-acting-like-32-bit-windows-on-64-bit-ubuntu)

Basically:

- remove ~/.wine

  export WINEARCH=win32

  wine iTunesXYZSetup.exe

Comment: I spotted a reference on WineHq [1] citing that you can rename .wine if you have existing programs installed. 

* - mv ~/.wine ~/.itunes
* - export
* - setup
* - mv ~/.itunes ~/.wine

[1] http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20551aa