# How Do I install iTunes 11 on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, itunes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install iTunes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166903/how-do-i-install-itunes)

I want to install and try out itunes 11 on ubuntu, but I don't really know how. I don't want to dual boot / use virtualbox to run windows.

Comment: Hope your will find this answer useful http://askubuntu.com/a/180084/9701

Comment: Basically, you contact Apple and ask for help.

Comment: Apple does not support linux (itunes) from what i knew @mikewhatever

Comment: True, but that doesn't mean it can't or shouldn't, ...and that's why, as a customer, you should tell them as much.