# How can I sync my iPad with Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS?

Tags: sync, ipad

I have an iPad 3rd Generation, it's called the New iPad, and I don't know how can I sync with my PC. I'm now using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you can try install itunes with `wine` to sync. You can see more [http://askubuntu.com/questions/166903/how-do-i-install-itunes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/166903/how-do-i-install-itunes)