# Installation Problem MS Office 2013 using Wine

Tags: wine

I try to install MS office 2013 in Ubuntu 12.10 using Wine. But It says:

```
error: newer windows version needed.
```

How Can I fix this error.

Comment: Check out this video. I think it's possible to have Office 2013 on Ubuntu but not using wine. you will have to use WinConn. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWu2le159K4

Comment: This video has been removed from Youtube. Can you elaborate on the technic it describes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Office 2013, won't be running on older operating systems like Windows XP and Vista, is only compatible with Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows Server 2012.

Open a terminal, type **winecfg**, and then select windows 7 from the drop down at the bottom of the window. If that doesn't work I suggest to look at this post :

- [Microsoft Office 2013 under wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26323).

Comment: so the answer is NO? "What works
Office_Professional_Plus_2013w_SP1_W32_English was tested. The installer can be started. Requires to change the windows version to a newer version than XP. I used Windows7. Than the installer crashes."


What does not
Installer crashes.

Answer (score 8):

Also, I needed dotnet20, which only installs in 32bit mode.

Thanks to [laurent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231587/installing-dotnet-2-0-on-64-bit-machine) the fix goes as follows

```
 env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winetricks dotnet20 msxml6 corefonts
```

Then run `env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winecfg` and select windows7 (thanks hhlp)

Then fix msxml6 (thanks [Richard W. @ liberiangeek.net](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/06/how-to-install-microsoft-office-suite-2010-in-ubuntu-12-04-using-wine-1-5/))

Finally install `env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 wine setup.exe`

Comment: This answer worked for me, whereas the other (hhlp) answer did not.

Comment: It's unclear what fix is needed for msxml6. You gave a link to LiberianGeek but that's not mentioning any specific fix

Comment: exactly. There are a lot of rumors going on. `dotnet20 msxml6` are not needed and `corefonts`is optional. We only really need `riched20` after the installation. See the winehq entry for details.