# wine: Install Mono for Windows to run .NET 2.0 applications

Tags: wine, mono

I just downloaded the GTA SA.. and it works fine with the SA:MP 0.3z RC2, but I have a big problem. There is a server which uses a secondary client. I tried to run it with WINE and Mono, but it still doesn't work. By the way, it needs .NET 2.0 on Windows, but I can't make it work on Ubuntu 12.04.

This is the client program:

```
http://data.hu/get/7493141/ClassRPG.exe
```

Error message when run by Wine:

```
wine: Install Mono for Windows to run .NET 2.0 applications.
```

Error message when run by Mono:

```
The entry point method could not be loaded.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

type this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-vbnc
mono ~/Downloads/ClassRPG.exe
```

assuming you downloaded the file in your home download directory and it is named ClassRPG.exe

Comment: I did it, installed mono-vbnc before, but it still says:
The entry point method could not be loaded

Comment: try to run the application from command line: `mono ~/Downloads/ClassRPG.exe`

Comment: I did, but as i said, it wont work:
metadata.c:886: assertion 'index < meta->heap_strings.size' failed
metadata.c:886: assertion 'index < meta->heap_strings.size' failed
metadata.c:886: assertion 'index < meta->heap_strings.size' failed
metadata.c:914: assertion 'index < meta->heap_blob.size' failed
metadata.c:914: assertion 'index < meta->heap_blob.size' failed
metadata.c:886: assertion 'index < meta->heap_strings.size'... 

and so on..at least it says:
The entry point method could not be loaded

Comment: install winetricks: `sudo apt-get install winetricks` then add dotnet 2.0 : `winetricks dotnet20`

Comment: I've got 64bit version i cant use that. Can you give me a 64bit version, please?

Comment: @user255875 check this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/231587/installing-dotnet-2-0-on-64-bit-machine

Comment: Does doesn't work for all .net apps. `Cannot open assembly './setup.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.`

Answer (score 4):

If the application in question is pure .Net and compatable with Mono, simply run:

`sudo apt-get install mono-complete`

Then run it from mono.

If not, you can use winetricks to install Mono or .Net in order to run it.

For .Net you need to be running a 32bit Wine bottle, but for wine-mono or mono you can run it on 64bit or 32bit