# Installing Office 2010 on Ubuntu 15.04 using Wine

Tags: 15.04, wine, microsoft-office

I had installed Office 2010 32bit on Ubuntu 12.04 before using guides such as [this](http://craigacgomez.blogspot.in/2012/09/installing-microsoft-office-2010-in.html). However, due to package changes, I was not able to replicate the same on Ubuntu 15.04.

How does one install Office 10 using Wine?

Comment: in step #4 of the instructions above, DO NOT create the wineprefix directory. winetricks will create it and set the appropriate WIN32 configuration. Otherwise, you may get the error: wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string, error message 'wine: WINEARCH set to win32 but '/home/<username>/.wineprefixes/office2010' is a 64-bit installation.'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Short version

Switching to the latest Wine version (1.7) and installing `winbind` were additional steps needed.

### Long version

The instructions are for Ubuntu 15.04 64bit. This borrows heavily from [Crag Gomez's guide](http://craigacgomez.blogspot.in/2012/09/installing-microsoft-office-2010-in.html), so thanks to him for a lot of these instructions.

1. Install the latest version of Wine - `dotnet20` installations cause issues otherwise

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get install wine winetricks
   ```
2. Install mesa OpenGL - may already exist, so the below commands would simply state that.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mesa-utils mesa-utils-extra libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev
   ```
3. Create softlinks for the 32bit OpenGL librariies (needed only for 64 bit systems)

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
   ```
4. Create a new `WINEPREFIX` for Office - this will be the directory that contains your files. You can use any directory, but I followed the standard Wineprefix directory (add your username).

   ```
   export WINEPREFIX="/home/<username>/.wineprefixes/office2010/"
   ```

Additionally, create that directory:

```
    mkdir -p /home/<username>/.wineprefixes/office2010/
```

5. Set the `WINEARCH` to 32 bit. Office 10 32 bit is the version that works best.

   ```
   export WINEARCH="win32"
   ```
6. Install `winbind`. Office installation stops midway if this is not done

   ```
   sudo apt-get install winbind
   ```
7. Install `dotnet20`, `msxml6` and `corefonts` modules using winetricks.

   Once you run the command you will be asked if you want to install a Mono package as well as a Gecko package - **select no for both**. `wine-mono` and `wine-gecko` should have already been installed when you installed `wine`

   ```
   winetricks dotnet20 msxml6 corefonts
   ```
8. Do the actual Windows install.

   Browse to the folder with the installation media and run

   ```
   wine setup.exe
   ```
9. Change settings for libraries in the wineprefix after installing

   - Run `winetricks`
   - Select **Run winecfg**. select the "Libraries" tab.
   - You should see **msxml6 (native, built-in)** in the **Existing overrides** section. Highlight it and click Edit and select **Native (Windows)** and click OK. Now, it should show up as ***msxml6 (native)**.
   - Then add the `riched20` and `gdiplus` libraries from the **New override for library** section and make sure these are also set as **"Native"**
10. Your office programs should show up in the Unity lenses.

Comment: Another tutorial: http://blog.z-proj.com/microsoft-office-2010-professional-pro-on-wine-1-6/

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/231605/308164) was necessary to install `dotnet20`. A similar process was needed to install `msxm16`. (I am on 64 bit).

Comment: I am facing a problem amid the installation: `Setup cannot find Access.en-us\Access.en-us\branding.xml. Browse to a valid installation source, and then click OK.` No way around it. Any idea?

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, the location of the 32bit OpenGL libraries appears to be a bit different.  As such, all that is required is:

      `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so`

Answer (score 0):

My machine is 64 bit and all the steps in the first answer worked for me, but in some winetricks commands I had to write something like the following:

```
env WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winetricks dotnet20
```

and I did the same for remaining `msxml6 corefonts`

Comment: I have never heard of that `enter code here` command. Looks interesting

Comment: I am not being able to install dotnet20 using winetricks as my machine is x64. Can you please clarify what should I write instead of "enter code here" in your answer for it?

Comment: This clearly is a mistake and I just found it funny. [Take a look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231587/installing-dotnet-2-0-on-64-bit-machine/231605#231605)