# Office 2010 on ubuntu “Wine is a 64 bit installation”

Tags: 16.04, wine, microsoft-office

I am trying to install Office 2010 on Ubuntu 16.04. I have a 32bit .iso file for Office. I am new to Linux and following steps from this answer: ([Installing Office 2010 on Ubuntu 15.04 using Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674692/installing-office-2010-on-ubuntu-15-04-using-wine)) 
After step 7 here is where I am stuck:

```
➜  ~ winetricks dotnet20                 
------------------------------------------------------
wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string, error message 'wine: WINEARCH set to win32 but '/home/something-something/.wine' is a 64-bit installation.'
------------------------------------------------------
➜  ~ wine setup.exe
wine: WINEARCH set to win32 but '/home/something-something/.wine' is a 64-bit installation.
```

What should I execute next to switch wine to 32bit? 
I do have .iso file for 64bit if Wine will allow that now.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing the `wine32` package.

Running

```
sudo apt install wine32
```

should take care it.