# game audio not working in Wine Ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: 14.04, wine, games, winetricks

I have recently migrated from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Everything works perfectly except for some things. I have successfully installed the two games I play often on Windows. Call of Duty World at War, and NBA 2k14. Both games run perfectly on Wine/PlayonLinux. Gameplay is terrific just like on native Windows. The only problem I encountered was there is no audio coming out from the game. My speakers do work however, outside of the game/s, when using YouTube or listening to music. I hypothesised that the problem was that there is no DirectX11 on my system. Could this be the cause of my problem? If not, what could it be? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

For NBA 2K14 According to [this](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=29140) report:

you have to install

```
vcrun2010
dxfullsetup
```

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine) post will help you do that.

Comment: If this works for both games you may consider accepting this as an answer.

Comment: im sorry my comment might have been misleading...i just liked that there was a fast answer. ok here is what happened. vcrun2010 succesfully installed thru winetricks. directx also installed but no sound yet. but then i followed the link you gave https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=29140..i had to install dotnet 2.0 and dsound. here was the problem. dsound installed fine but dotnet 2.0 couldnt be installed because it wouldnt work on 64 bit computer. i then followed this http://askubuntu.com/questions/231587/installing-dotnet-2-0-on-64-bit-machine, to install dotnet 2.0

Comment: now the installation said that dotnet 2.0 installed correctly.  i still wondered because in winetricks, dotnet2.0 still appeared not installed. and then after testing if what i did worked, i launched cod waw and nba 2k14, and still no sound came out. any suggestions on what i should do? thanks so much :)