# How do I get around OS checks in wine?

Tags: 12.04, wine, playonlinux, camera

I got a Lytro from woot this week, but didn't research the Linux support. I have PlayOnLinux installed and was hoping to run the windows software from there. The snag I ran into was that they have an OS check. How do I get around this?

[image: Unfortunately your computer does not meet the minimum requirements. Only 64-bit Windows 7 Windows 8 is supported.]

Comment: Idk about playonlinux, but on Wine you can set a new wineprefix with 64bits support.

Comment: I made a prefix. and got past that message... not what do I do about lack of dotnet 4.5 support? Or dotnet support on 64 bit computers?

Comment: No idea, isn't Mono (pretty much open-source dotnet) enough ?

Comment: mono supports apps outside of wine AFAIK. Giving up for tonight here is my error log for running the installed app. http://pastebin.com/Zq0YteWX

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/wine-mono0.0.8

Comment: and for your missing dll error `winetricks vcrun2010`, said Google.

Comment: tried that... but it installs these in the wrong prefix ~/.local/share/wineprefixes/Lytro but PlayOnLinux installs prefixes in ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Lytro so maybe I can copy them over... will try tomorrow.

Comment: There is an option in playonlinux to install vcrun2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to already answered question :

[How to force Wine into acting like 32-bit Windows on 64-bit Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136714/how-to-force-wine-into-acting-like-32-bit-windows-on-64-bit-ubuntu)

you can  switch between  32 and 64-bit windows by changing  WINEARCH environment variable.

Comment: I ran into other issues, but will make another question for it.