# Problem installing WinBUGs with Wine

Tags: kernel, wine

On 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 (Linux kernel 3.13.0.30.36) I'm trying to install the [WinBUGS](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/software/bugs/the-bugs-project-winbugs/) Markov Chain Monte Carlo software with Wine 1.6, but after

```
wine WinBUGS14.exe
```

I get the following error message:

```
modify_ldt: Invalid argument
modify_ldt: Invalid argument
modify_ldt: Invalid argument
modify_ldt: Invalid argument
modify_ldt: Invalid argument
err:module:attach_process_dlls "krnl386.exe16" failed to initialize, aborting
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winevdm.exe" failed, status c0000005
```

There seems to be some discussion of the problem [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/kernel-3-14-4-and-the-nvidia-drivers-and-wine-4175504913/)—something to do with incompatability between certain kernel versions & certain Wine versions for 16-bit applications.

What options do I have? If there's a way to install an older version of Wine on Ubuntu 14.04 it would suit me fine, as I remember WinBUGS running with Wine 1.4, & I don't use Wine for running anything else.

(I already use the alternative MCMC software, JAGS, but I'll be needing WinBUGS for a course.)

Comment: Have you tried a 32-bit Wine setup? 64-bit Windows can't run 16-bit programs, but 32-bit Windows can. I'm assuming it's the same thing with Wine.

Comment: @saiarcot895: I'm not honestly sure. If I haven't, am I right in thinking the steps [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/136714/) will give me a 32-bit Wine set-up? (I don't know whether the application is in fact a 16-bit one, but that sounds worth trying)

Comment: I believe so. It's been a while since I set up a Wine chroot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed @saiarcot895's instructions to make a 32-bit Wine set-up, but got the same error. I then noticed the instructions [here](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/software/bugs/the-bugs-project-winbugs/): "If installing on a 64-bit machine, you should download a zipped version of the whole file structure and unzip it into Program Files or wherever you want it."—rather than using the installer. So I extracted the file to `.wine/drive_c/Program Files`, & now WinBUGS works. Not sure if both those steps were necessary or just the latter.