# ubuntu 32 bit vs 64 bit when using lots of windows applications

Tags: 32-bit

I have acer laptop with processor capable of running 64 bit programs. I also love windows applications and would be using `wine` to install lots of them. So in your opinion should I use 32 bit OS to avoid all the nasty problems arise because of 64 bit architecture during windows application installs?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about the "nasty problems" you expect to avoid by using 32 bit Ubuntu. I have been using 64 bit Linux installations for nearly 10 years now. And while I use WINE not that extensively I have yet to encounter any problems that have to do specifically with running 32bit Windows programs on a 64bit Linux.

Comment: i am new to linux environment and so far my experience has been encouraging due to wonderful community of nice people.  by nasty problems i mean architecture conflicts, different apps written architectures, compatibility issues,  need to install extra packages to make it run on amd64.  i know to make it run on amd64, i have to put extra time and effort but can i avoid them altogether by installing 32 bit OS

Answer (score 0):

My advice: Install Ubuntu 64 bit

You can then tell wine to act as a Windows 32bit system without a problem. You will need to edit `~/.bashrc` and add `export WINEARCH=win32` to the end of the file.

Use this article for more in-depth answer to this problem: 
[How to force Wine into acting like 32-bit Windows on 64-bit Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136714/how-to-force-wine-into-acting-like-32-bit-windows-on-64-bit-ubuntu)