# How to run WineTricks in 32 bit mode on a 64 bit system

Tags: wine, winetricks, multiarch

I am using WineTricks to install some DLLs, but I'm encountering this problem when installing .NET framework:

[image: This product is not supported on a 64-bit OS.]

So, how do I run WineTricks in 32-bit mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/136714/how-to-force-wine-into-acting-like-32-bit-windows-on-64-bit-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Set up a 32 bit [Wine Bottle Prefix on a 64-bit System by using Wine Bottles](http://www.myscienceisbetter.info/how-to-create-a-new-wine-prefix-or-bottle.html), like so:

32-bit:
`winearch=win32 WINEPREFIX="/path/to/new/wine/bottle" winecfg`

64-bit:
`winearch=win64 WINEPREFIX="/path/to/new/wine/bottle" winecfg`

---

Never use the default WINE bottle.  Use winetricks to select the bottle.

Comment: just to add a tip, when running a 32bit application on a 64bit prefix, while calling `wine64`, we need to `unset WINEARCH` b4 calling it, or it will also give "bad exe  format" error