# Winetricks 32-bit wineprefix

Tags: command-line, wine, 32-bit, winetricks

I am attmempting to install visual studio using wine, and I am using Winetricks to install it. When I open Winetricks, I get a warning that says, "You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug". I could continue to the next page, but I wanted to resolve it just to make sure that my installation would go smoothly. I looked around on Google and Ask Ubuntu and I found many similar questions, but nothign really worked until I found a soloution that told me to enter

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot
```

and I got

```
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/matthew/prefix32'
002c:fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
0048:fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
0050:fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
0050:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:start_rpcss Failed to open RpcSs service
0048:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
0048:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x4b2020, 0): stub
0048:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (00010020, 004B2020): stub
002c:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x481cc0, 1): stub
002c:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0001004E, 00481CC0): stub
0090:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x42a990, 1): stub
0090:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (00010086, 0042A990): stub
0090:fixme:urlmon:InternetBindInfo_GetBindString not supported string type 20
0090:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0090:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0090:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0090:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0090:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0090:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
00a4:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
00a4:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
00a4:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
00a4:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
00a4:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
00a4:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
00a4:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 5)
00a4:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 5)
0090:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
0090:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
wine: configuration in L"/home/matthew/prefix32" has been updated.
```

as a respone from the terminal. I noticed a lot of errors throughout it, but at the end it said that the configuration was updated so I thought it worked. It did not. I got the same response. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/766162/how-to-run-winetricks-in-32-bit-mode-on-a-64-bit-system?rq=1

Comment: @Nmath This error is happening before I can attempt to install the application, so I don't think that disclosing the software is needed in this question, but I did edit the post and I am attempting to install Visual Studio

Comment: @Nmath That's vs code. I just want Visual studio. It might not be possible but I want to find out if I can get visual studio

Comment: It's not practical to run an IDE over emulation and compatibility layers. Wine is not the answer here. I suggest that you look into dual boot config, or run Windows in a virtual machine

Comment: @Nmath Okay Thanks