# Hearthstone stucks on black screen, Intel gpu issue?

Tags: wine, playonlinux, winetricks

### Background:

The first time I installed the hearthstone with the file downloaded from blizzard via "Installing a non-listed program". In that time luncher was loaded and the only problem was starting hearthstone it stuck at a black screen.

The second time I tried to download on the list of POL. First time I got errors but second time after I got error and Battle.net Luncher did not install and crashed. I just copied the Blizzard app folder from the old download and replaced it.

Battle.net Luncher is running and I can login and when I click play and Hearthstone starts just a Black screen appears and that's all I get !

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64
Wine 2.01 x86 system set: windows xp ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/139254/706129))

PlayonLinux 4.2.10
wine 2.12-stagin
wine 1.9.18

Libraries:
msvcp140(native,builtin)
dbghelp(disabled)

### Main Questions:

I can't install `wininet` while `winetricks wininet` command or `PlayonLinux Configuration > Install Components > wininet` does not work because they both link to download from MS servers and this file is deleted from their servers.

**Q**: while I can login and even the Luncher loads its news that means I have no problem of connecting to servers, is it necessary to install `wininet` ? (while it only interacts with HTTP protocols to connect to Internet)

**Q**: According to this [Workaround For Black / Distorted Battle.net UI On Linux (Wine) With Intel Graphics](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/partial-workaround-for-black-distorted.html) while I could not update my Intel graphic driver, even I tried to install [Intel Graphics Update Tool for Linux* OS v2.0.2](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2) but I couldn't install it. It stuck at middle of installing via `Software Install`.

`LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program*/[Folder name]/"Battle.net Launcher.exe"`
or
`wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program*/[Folder name]/"Battle.net Launcher.exe" -opengl`
did not work.

Answer (score 2):

These steps worked for me:

1) Install: `$ winetricks dotnet40`

2) On the battle.net app, go on hearthsone page, click on the **Options** then open the **Game Settings** now check the **Additional command line arguments** and type there : `-force-d3d9`

3) Change your wine windows version to windows 7

4) Terminate all your wine apps and now start your hearthstone